# kendoDatePicker not working on firefox

Tags: firefox, kendo-datepicker

kendoDatePicker is coming blank on firefox after i have just given the max property as below :

```
 $("#ABC").kendoDatePicker({
        max: new Date("31-DEC-2199")
    });
```

but to my surprise same is working fine on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

it was just the Dateformat : it should be like

```
$("#ABC").kendoDatePicker({
    max: new Date("12/31/2199")
});
```